# ruby app is giving problems with incompatible libraries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos

while generating controllers, I am getting this error message:

```
Leticias-MacBook-Pro:portfolio Tish$ rails g controller welcome index about music loops projects
/Users/Tish/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.12/lib/sqlite3.rb:6:in `require': incompatible library version - /Users/Tish/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.12/lib/sqlite3/sqlite3_native.bundle (fatal)
    from /Users/Tish/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.12/lib/sqlite3.rb:6:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
    from /Users/Tish/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.12/lib/sqlite3.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/Tish/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:91:in `require'
    from /Users/Tish/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:91:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from /Users/Tish/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:86:in `each'
    from /Users/Tish/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:86:in `block in require'
    from /Users/Tish/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:75:in `each'
    from /Users/Tish/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:75:in `require'
    from /Users/Tish/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler.rb:106:in `require'
    from /Users/Tish/Projects/portfolio/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/Tish/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/spring-2.0.0/lib/spring/application.rb:82:in `require'
    from /Users/Tish/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/spring-2.0.0/lib/spring/application.rb:82:in `preload'
    from /Users/Tish/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/spring-2.0.0/lib/spring/application.rb:143:in `serve'
    from /Users/Tish/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/spring-2.0.0/lib/spring/application.rb:131:in `block in run'
    from /Users/Tish/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/spring-2.0.0/lib/spring/application.rb:125:in `loop'
    from /Users/Tish/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/spring-2.0.0/lib/spring/application.rb:125:in `run'
    from /Users/Tish/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/spring-2.0.0/lib/spring/application/boot.rb:19:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

Nothing I have tried makes it stop.  I have reinstalled every gem it complains about, but the changes do not persist.  I've followed every fix I can find/understand but I am chasing my tail on this one.
Working on OSX...

Comment: Are you using a Ruby version manager like chruby or rvm? Are you sure it's loaded?

Comment: I'm using rvm : this error has also been a headache, but not my biggest    headache...
    Warning! PATH is not properly set up, '/Users/Tish/.rvm/gems/ruby-    2.3.1/bin' is not at first place,
         usually this is caused by shell initialization files - check them for 'PATH=...' entries,
         it might also help to re-add RVM to your dotfiles: 'rvm get stable --auto-dotfiles',
         to fix temporarily in this shell session run: 'rvm use ruby-2.3.1'.
rvm 1.27.0 (latest) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]

Comment: The message is pretty clear, and has been asked and answered already on this site. RVM isn't set up right, and you're probably using your system ruby.

Answer (score 1):

Your rails is not linked with the right ruby version. Use the following code:

`rvm use ruby-<version number>` like: (rvm use ruby-2.1.4)

then reinstall the bundler:

```
gem uninstall bundler
gem install bundler
```

bundle install once again with the new version.

```
bundle install
```

Then proceed with your rails g command.